# wxPython Application displaying blank screen on startup

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I've a wxPython application. It's just an example application whose functionality is non-important.

I can launch the program successfully on my Ubuntu desktop, however, on Windows 10 I receive an initial blank screen. It is only until I resize the screen *slightly* that the contents of the application show up.

Is there a specific reason for this issue?

### Code

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """ We simply derive a new class of Frame. """
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super().__init__(parent, title=title, size=(600,400)) 
        self.Show(True)


class ExamplePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # create some sizers
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        grid = wx.GridBagSizer(hgap=5, vgap=5)
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.quote = wx.StaticText(self, label="Your quote: ")
        grid.Add(self.quote, pos=(0,0))

        # A multiline TextCtrl - This is here to show how the events work in this program, don't pay too much attention to it
        self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(200,300), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)

        # A button
        self.button =wx.Button(self, label="Save")

        # the edit control - one line version.
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(self, label="Your name :")
        grid.Add(self.lblname, pos=(1,0))
        self.editname = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="Enter here your name", size=(140,-1))
        grid.Add(self.editname, pos=(1,1))


        # the combobox Control
        self.sampleList = ['friends', 'advertising', 'web search', 'Yellow Pages']
        self.lblhear = wx.StaticText(self, label="How did you hear from us ?")
        grid.Add(self.lblhear, pos=(3,0))
        self.edithear = wx.ComboBox(self, size=(95, -1), choices=self.sampleList, style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN)
        grid.Add(self.edithear, pos=(3,1))

        # add a spacer to the sizer
        grid.Add((10, 40), pos=(2,0))

        # Checkbox
        self.insure = wx.CheckBox(self, label="Do you want Insured Shipment ?")
        grid.Add(self.insure, pos=(4,0), span=(1,2), flag=wx.BOTTOM, border=5)

        # Radio Boxes
        radioList = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'orange', 'green', 'purple', 'navy blue', 'black', 'gray']
        rb = wx.RadioBox(self, label="What color would you like ?", pos=(20, 210), choices=radioList,  majorDimension=3,
                        style=wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS)
        grid.Add(rb, pos=(5,0), span=(1,2))

        hSizer.Add(grid, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hSizer.Add(self.logger)
        mainSizer.Add(hSizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.CENTER)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(mainSizer)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(useBestVisual=True)
    frame = MyFrame(None, title="Demo with Notebook")
    nb = wx.Notebook(frame)

    nb.AddPage(ExamplePanel(nb), "Absolute Positioning")
    nb.AddPage(ExamplePanel(nb), "Page Two")
    nb.AddPage(ExamplePanel(nb), "Page Three")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution was to write cleaner, more organized code. In addition to cleaner code, I included the following at the bottom of `MainFrame`.

```
# finally, put the notebook in a sizer for the panel to manage
# the layout
sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
p.SetSizer(sizer)
sizer.Fit(p)
p.Layout()
```

Working code below:

```
import wx


# Some classes to use for the notebook pages.  Obviously you would
# want to use something more meaningful for your application, these
# are just for illustration.

class ExamplePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # create some sizers
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        grid = wx.GridBagSizer(hgap=5, vgap=5)
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.quote = wx.StaticText(self, label="Your quote: ")
        grid.Add(self.quote, pos=(0,0))

        # A multiline TextCtrl - This is here to show how the events work in this program, don't pay too much attention to it
        self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(200,300), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)

        # A button
        self.button =wx.Button(self, label="Save")

        # the edit control - one line version.
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(self, label="Your name :")
        grid.Add(self.lblname, pos=(1,0))
        self.editname = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="Enter here your name", size=(140,-1))
        grid.Add(self.editname, pos=(1,1))


        # the combobox Control
        self.sampleList = ['friends', 'advertising', 'web search', 'Yellow Pages']
        self.lblhear = wx.StaticText(self, label="How did you hear from us ?")
        grid.Add(self.lblhear, pos=(3,0))
        self.edithear = wx.ComboBox(self, size=(95, -1), choices=self.sampleList, style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN)
        grid.Add(self.edithear, pos=(3,1))

        # add a spacer to the sizer
        grid.Add((10, 40), pos=(2,0))

        # Checkbox
        self.insure = wx.CheckBox(self, label="Do you want Insured Shipment ?")
        grid.Add(self.insure, pos=(4,0), span=(1,2), flag=wx.BOTTOM, border=5)

        # Radio Boxes
        radioList = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'orange', 'green', 'purple', 'navy blue', 'black', 'gray']
        rb = wx.RadioBox(self, label="What color would you like ?", pos=(20, 210), choices=radioList,  majorDimension=3,
                        style=wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS)
        grid.Add(rb, pos=(5,0), span=(1,2))

        hSizer.Add(grid, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hSizer.Add(self.logger)
        mainSizer.Add(hSizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.CENTER)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(mainSizer)


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Simple Notebook Example")

        # Here we create a panel and a notebook on the panel
        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p)

        # create the page windows as children of the notebook
        page1 = ExamplePanel(nb)
        page2 = ExamplePanel(nb)
        page3 = ExamplePanel(nb)

        # add the pages to the notebook with the label to show on the tab
        nb.AddPage(page1, "Page 1")
        nb.AddPage(page2, "Page 2")
        nb.AddPage(page3, "Page 3")

        # finally, put the notebook in a sizer for the panel to manage
        # the layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Fit(p)
        p.Layout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```